# roku/brightscript - how to access screen elements from main function

Tags: roku, brightscript

This seems like a basic use case, but I can't find any examples of it anywhere!

I've made a Scene, containing a Label, with id=myLabel.  I want to access this label in my main.brs file, so that I can update the text as messages come in.  I've tried every way I can think of, but can't get it to work!

This is essentially all I want to do in main.brs:

m.top.myLabel.text="hello"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Your main.brs try:

```
Scene.findNode("myLabel").text = "some text"
```

Where `Scene` is Your scene reference and `"myLabel"` is an id of your label inside of that scene.